# Laravel vite, Failed to load PostCSS config

Tags: laravel, vite, postcss

После установки breeze в Laravel в корне сайта появляется файл `postcss.config.js`:
**postcss.config.js**

```
export default {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
};
```

и перестаёт работать команда `npm run dev | build`, до этого работала, выдаёт ошибку:

```
[vite:css] Failed to load PostCSS config [SyntaxError] Unexpected token 'export'  
postcss.config.js:1
export default {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

vite ведь по идее понимает новый синтаксис js.
И дело в том что если закомментировать файл `postcss.config.js` то эта ошибка пропадает.
Подскажите какое есть решение чтобы обойти эту проблему не комментируя файл `postcss.config.js`?

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

пытался сюда добавлять `target: 'es2020',` не поменялось ничего
**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "sass": "^1.62.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

Если переименовать `postcss.config.js` в `postcss.config.mjs` будет ли это правильное решение?

Comment: Вроде как для vite 3+ надо чтоб расширение было `.cjs`

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо удалить папку **node_modules**

потом действовать согласно инструкции для установки Tailwind под [Laravel](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel)

в конце выполнить команду **npm install && npm run dev**